# cancelAllLocalNotifications; not working on iPhone 3GS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

So my app has been around for 5 days now and iPhone 3GS users are reporting that their notifications doesn't cancel when the button is switched.
The button executes the following code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

However, this code works on iPhone 4,iPhone 4S,iPhone 5 and iPad.
Is this a known bug of the iPhone 3GS? Or does the 3GS require different code to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why but I had to cancel all notification by notifcation ID instead of CancelAll on iPhone 3GS

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into this problem on iOS 8.1 on an iPhone 6+.  It turns out that cancelAllLocalNotifications is not a synchronous call, so there is no guarantee that the cancelation has been completed when it returns.  I've had to implement the following as a workaround

```
- (void) clearNotifications
{
    NSLog(@"Clearing notifications");
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    long count;
    while ((count = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]) > 0) {
        NSLog(@"Remaining notificaitons to cancel: %lu",(unsigned long)count);
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:.01f];
    }
    NSLog(@"Notifications cleared");
}
```

Comment: This method worked for me, but could you explain what is sleepForTimeInterval for?